# WinAPI failure. win 8.1 (build 9431) as win 8 (build 9200)

Tags: windows, windows-8

I'm using `GetVersionEx` WinAPI call to get info about system. However it returns wrong build number for `Windows 8.1`.

Have been looking info but didn't find about that. It is probably windows bug but want to ask and be sure if `Windows 8.1` support all previous API calls.

Answer (score 1):

GetVersionEx is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) since Windows 8.1. If you where just interested in if you are running on Windows 8.1, then you could use [Version Helper functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Since you want to know the build number, you need to [change the Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to tell Windows that your app supports Windows 8.1. You need to add `<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>` to the `<assembly><compatibility><application>` node.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to get build number as `GetVersion` is also deprecated.

Comment: @ST3: Did you follow the links in my answer? Now I also put the needed changes directly into the answer.

Comment: @ST3: If you think my answer is correct, I'ld appreciate if you accept it.